# General insertion sort algorithm not moving the first object in list

Tags: c++17

I need to create a  general insertion sort algorithm using move semantics. I have it working for entire lists of different types of objects except for the very first object in the list.

```
template<typename Iter, typename Comparator>
void insertionSort(const Iter& begin, const Iter& end, Comparator compareFn)
{
    for (auto i = begin + 1; i < end; i++)
    {
        auto currentthing = std::move(*i);
        auto j = std::move(i - 1);

        while (j >= begin and compareFn(*j, currentthing))
        {
            *(j + 1) = std::move(*j);
            if (j == begin)
                break;
            j--;
        }
        *(j + 1) = std::move(currentthing);
    }    
}
```

Where comparing a list of strings from my main function:

```
int main()
{
    vector<int> numbers = { 0, 1, 8, 4, 2, 9, 5, 3, 6, 7, 10 };
    insertionSort(numbers.begin(), numbers.end(), std::less<int>());

    cout << "Sorted: " << numbers << "\n";

    vector<string> names = { "p", "a", "b", "d", "c", "f", "e" };
    insertionSort(names.begin(), names.end(), std::greater<string>());

    cout << "Sorted: " << names << "\n";

    return 0;
}
```

Outputs the following

```
Sorted: [ 0 10 9 8 7 6 5 4 3 2 1 ]
Sorted: [  a b c d e f ]
```

Answer (score 0):

The while loop should break when `j` equals `i` and not when `j` equals `begin`. So, the following:

```
if (j == begin)
    break;
```

should actually be:

```
if (j == i)
    break;
```